# Divide matrix into n matrices

Tags: java, matrix, divide

I have an N x N matrix (which is generated randomly).

I need to divide it into C matrices (C is the number of matrices the user provides).

For example, if the 4 X 4 matrix we have is:

```
0     5     6     9
3     0     1     3
8     1     0     2
9     2     4     0
```

and the user enters 2 as C, then the result should be:

```
Matrix 1
    0     5     6     9
    3     0     1     3

Matrix 2
    8     1     0     2
    9     2     4     0
```

Comment: what is the logic to print matrix 1????

Comment: Does it have to be explicit? How are the matrices stored?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I tried to copy the regular matrix, try loop to print it, but not working like this, it shows part of the matrix, please any help, idea are appreciated

Comment: to Joe, I've done most of the code, and this is part of it, I couldn't add my code because other student will use it, and I worked hard to make it

Comment: @Greital What LOGIC you want for SPLITTING the original matrix?!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TestMain {

    int[][] rr = new int[][]{
        {0, 5, 6, 9},
        {3, 0, 1, 3},
        {8, 1, 0, 2},
        {9, 2, 4, 0}};

    public TestMain() {
        getHalfMatrix(rr);
    }

    public void getHalfMatrix(int[][] mrix) {
        int st = (int) mrix.length / 2;
        System.out.print("Matrix1\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < st; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mrix[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("\t" + mrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        System.out.print("Matrix2\n");
        for (int i = st; i < mrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mrix[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("\t" + mrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestMain();

    }

}
```

OUTPUT is:

```
Matrix1
    0   5   6   9
    3   0   1   3
Matrix2
    8   1   0   2
    9   2   4   0
```